# How to sort right decimal numbers

Tags: powershell, regex, sorting

I have a folder that contains sub-folders for each application version(decimal number). Now, I have a `powershell` script for version comparison. The problem is I can't sort it as expected. How can I solve it in one line code, because I am doing it from batch script.

Using `Get-ChildItem` to see folder content

Current sort(executing from `batch` script:

`powershell -Command "& {Get-ChildItem "\folder_dir\" -Name | sort-object -descending }`

Options for solution:

1. Sort `Get-ChildItem` by date, and somehow print only the names of the folders(without the title "Name" like as in regular output)
2. Sort `Get-ChildItem` by name, and somehow to sort it(the problem is with decimal numbers)

For example(descending or ascending, doesn't matter. The order is what is matter):

```
Folder content:
1.0
1.111
1.11
2.2
1.18
2.5
2.44

Current output:
2.5 <-- wrong place
2.44
2.2
1.18 <-- wrong place
1.111
1.11
1.0

Expected sort:
1.0
1.11
1.18
1.111
2.2
2.5
2.44
```

Comment: Closest answer was in [link](http://blog.davotronic5000.co.uk/when-sort-object-does-not-sort/). But I don't have letters, only numbers

Comment: What you're looking for is natural sorting. [This](https://gist.github.com/markwragg/e2a9dc05f3464103d6998298fb575d4e) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427506/how-to-sort-by-file-name-the-same-way-windows-explorer-does) might be helpful. As for your example why would you not be able to adapt it? It's just that you would split using the dot and sort each group?

Comment: Convoluted but it matches your sample: `Get-ChildItem "\folder_dir\" -Name | sort $("{0}.{1}" -f ($_ -replace '^(.*?)\.\d+$', '$1'), ($_ -replace '^.*?\.(\d+)$', '$1').PadLeft(10, "0"))`

Comment: @Seth 's nartual sorting example works.

Comment: @Seth solution worked. Final command: `powershell -Command "& {Get-ChildItem "\\nas\shared\Public\Igor\gscript\version" -Name | sort-object { [regex]::Replace($_, '\d+', { $args[0].Value.PadLeft(20) }) }}`

Comment: Instead of leaving it as comment consider writing an actual answer (maybe with some background/links) and accept it yourself. :)

Comment: Says "you can accept your own answer in 2 days", will wait then.

Answer (score 2):

Credit to @Seth solution

From [link](https://gist.github.com/markwragg/e2a9dc05f3464103d6998298fb575d4e)

Final command: `powershell -Command "& {Get-ChildItem "\\nas\shared\Public\Igor\gscript\version" -Name | sort-object { [regex]::Replace($_, '\d+', { $args[0].Value.PadLeft(20) }) }}`

Comment: The sort-object regex worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your script is working perfectly.

You have sort in descending order, and that is exactly what it does.

Notice that the number on the left of the . also goes from high to low.

So your script would need to be as follows:

```
powershell -Command "& {Get-ChildItem "\\nas\shared\Public\Igor\gscript\version" 
   -Name | sort-object }
```

Sort-Object sorts in ascending order by default unless -descending is used.

Comment: (1)There is no "ascending"  for sort-object in ps  (2)My script doesn't work properly, look at the description

Comment: @igor my bad. It does ascending by default, unless you set -descending. Edited my answer to reflect.